# Relationship from Orders to Shop and Supplier, or to general User?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a platform where

- a User can have a Shop, which can place Orders
- a User can be a Supplier, which can see Orders from Shops coming in.

I have created the following diagram depicting the structure I have modeled so far:

[image]

Is that a *good* schema? Or, would it make more sense to *couple* the relationships to the User straight away?

I'm guessing that will cause more overhead in my backend? (Laravel - PHP)

Thank you!

Comment: Use the Party Model, Luke

Comment: One test for goodness of schema comes when you try to write the `SELECTs`.

Answer (score 0):

Following are my comments:

- Users info should be isolated from Other Entities like shop, Supplier etc
- Association between User and Shop should be moved to User_Shop table
- Association between User and Supplier should be moved to User_Supplier table
- There should be association between Shop and Supplier to view the Order from specific Shop by Supplier in the table Shop_Supplier.
- There should be a table namely Order_Fulfil to map the orders fulfilled by Suppliers
- Not sure about the mapping between the Product and User. Ideally there should be mapping between shop and product and order and Product.

Comment: Logically, `User_Shop` should only be needed if both a user can have multiple shops, and a shop can have multiple users. The same holds true for `User_Supplier`.

Answer (score 0):

Relationship tables (such as User_Shop) are only needed in many-to-many (M:N) relationships, so you don't need User_Shop, Shop_Supplier,...

The User-Supplier relationship is interesting.

Does a record in the Supplier table represent a user who is also a supplier? In other words, a person? If so, the User-Supplier relationship is 1:0..1 (a User may be associated to zero or one Supplier, but a Supplier is only associated to a single User). Usually, this kind of relationship is mapped to a single table with nullable fields.

Now, if Supplier represents a company, and you have multiple users associated to the same company, a proper 1:N relationship seems more adequate.

As an aside, do not store the password in plaintext in your database. Follow proper password management best practices.